# Visio 2016 - Issue while creating org chart, how to keep same width/height for all shapes

Tags: visio

We are trying to create org chart in Visio using wizard by providing excel file and then saving as web page

We are creating separate page for all the executives. Now issue is if executive has less no. of reportees the shapes are coming good as below

[image]

But if reportees are more, then shapes are coming very small which are not readable at all

[image]

The question is, how to keep the shape size same as in image 1, so that it can be readable?

Answer (score 0):

For the last 2 column, you may try to put it in 3-4 columns.

Re [P S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1482298/p-s):
Can you?

- select the boxes and choose required width/height
- break down the org chart, one for department and some for persons

Comment: I tried that, but still shapes are small. I want shapes to have fixed width/height across all pages.